# get 'related' data from several tables with a single query in PHP/MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm developing a small PHP app from scratch to practice/learn. The goal is to be able to create articles. Each article can have tags and images, stored in their own tables. 
Since an article can have many tags and a single tag can be present in many articles, I also created a 'tag/article' association table.

Now, when I want to edit or display an article, I get its data (plus tags and images) by doing several DB requests... for example, given an article id, I do something like:

```
$article = getArticle($articleId);
$tags = getArticleTags($articleId);
$images = getArticleImages($articleId);
```

It works, but I'm not sure if it's a clean approach and good performance-wise.
So I was wondering, **can this be done by using a single query?**
I tried but got a bit confused with UNIONs and JOINs.
If not, is there any better/recommended approach to achieve this?

The (simplified) tables I'm using are:

articles table:

```
┌-----┬------------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ title            │ dateCreated            │
├-----┼------------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ some article     │ 2015-03-17 12:38:49    │
├-----┼------------------┼------------------------┤
│ 2   │ article two      │ 2015-03-17 15:00:24    │
└-----┴------------------┴------------------------┘
```

tags table:

```
┌-----┬------------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ name             │ dateCreated            │
├-----┼------------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ php              │ 2015-03-17 15:01:05    │
├-----┼------------------┼------------------------┤
│ 2   │ jquery           │ 2015-03-17 15:24:12    │
└-----┴------------------┴------------------------┘
```

tag-article association table:

```
┌-----┬--------┬-------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ tagId  │ articleId   │ dateCreated            │
├-----┼--------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1           │ 2015-03-17 15:01:06    │
├-----┼--------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 2   │ 2      │ 1           │ 2015-03-17 15:24:58    │
├-----┼--------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 3   │ 1      │ 2           │ 2015-03-17 15:30:38    │
└-----┴--------┴-------------┴------------------------┘
```

article-images table:

```
┌-----┬-----------┬-------------┬------------------------┐
│ id  │ fileName  │ articleId   │ dateCreated            │
├-----┼-----------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 1   │ pic1.jpg  │ 1           │ 2015-03-17 16:05:26    │
├-----┼-----------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 2   │ pic2.jpg  │ 1           │ 2015-03-17 16:06:29    │
├-----┼-----------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 3   │ dog.jpg   │ 2           │ 2015-03-17 17:00:14    │
├-----┼-----------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 4   │ cat.jpg   │ 2           │ 2015-03-17 17:01:06    │
├-----┼-----------┼-------------┼------------------------┤
│ 5   │ bird.jpg  │ 2           │ 2015-03-17 17:02:34    │
└-----┴-----------┴-------------┴------------------------┘
```

Also, I'm using PDO this way, for example, to get an article:

```
    public function getArticleById($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':id' => $id);
        $result = $query->execute($parameters);
        return ($result) ? $query->fetch() : 0;
    }
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

### **UPDATE:**

@Adrian's answer is close to what I'm looking for and partially solves the question. It returns the following [image]

The thing is that the id columns are ambiguous and I can't figure out how to end up with a clean array like this, ideally:

```
Array
(
    [title] => some article
    [id] => 1
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => php
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => jquery
                )

        )

    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [fileName] => pic1.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [fileName] => pic2.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Then, combining both Daniel's and Adrian's answers, I ended up with this query, which returns something more readable that (I guess) I could process to achieve the above mentioned array (I imagine that iterating and removing duplicates):

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.title, 
    a.dateCreated as articleDate,
    i.id as imageId,
    i.fileName as imageFile,
    t.id as tagId,
    t.name as tagName
FROM 
    articles a
JOIN 
    article_tags ta ON a.id = ta.articleId
JOIN
    tags t ON ta.tagId = t.id

JOIN 
    images i ON a.id = i.articleId


WHERE 
    a.id = 1
```

This returns:

[image]

performance-wise, since this possible solution returns many rows with duplicated data (depending on how many tags and images are associated with an article). **Is this better than doing the initial multiple calls I started with?**

Comment: learn about the joy of [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @sunburst you must close this question and open another, as I say in my answer, in this moment you was edit the question and now your question is "primarily opinion-based" the users can flag it an the admins will close your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to achieve what I wanted, by combining the answers posted by @Adrian and @Daniel who pointed me in the right direction (thanks!) and adding the use of CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT and CAST (to mix int and varchar).

I upvoted both answers, which solved the problem partially, but I thought I should post my own answer since (I think) is a cleaner solution, at least for what I wanted, and it may help someone else.

Here's the SQL

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( t.id AS CHAR( 50 ) ) ,  ':', t.name ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS  'tags', 
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST( i.id AS CHAR( 50 ) ) ,  ':', i.fileName ORDER BY i.id SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS  'images'
FROM 
  articles a
JOIN 
  article_tags ta ON a.id = ta.articleId
JOIN 
  images i ON a.id = i.articleId
JOIN 
  tags t ON ta.tagId = t.id
WHERE 
  a.id = :id
```

This query returns the following, with id = 1:

[image]

A single row containing the article's data, its tags and images in a id:value format, which I think it's very easy to parse in PHP and can even be used to return a json string by just adding another concat.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.title, 
    a.dateCreated as articleDate,
    i.fileName as imageFile,
    t.name as tagName
FROM 
    articles a
JOIN 
    images i ON a.id = i.articleId
JOIN 
    tag_article ta ON a.id = ta.articleId
JOIN
    tags t ON ta.articleId = t.id
WHERE 
    a.id = ?
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, if I run this query with article id=1, it returns  [the following 4 rows](http://i.imgur.com/BCqEKDO.png)
but I can't get all tags (article with id=1 has both tags associated).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

EDIT:

```
$sql = "SELECT
articles.id, 
articles.title, 
articles.dateCreated as articleDate,
article-images.id as imageId,
article-images.fileName as imageFile,
tags.id as tagId,
tags.name as tagName
FROM articles
JOIN tag-article ON articles.id = tag-article.articleId
JOIN tags ON tag-article.tagId = tags.id
JOIN article-images ON article-images.articleId = articles.id
WHERE articles.id=:id"

$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$parameters = array(':id' => $id);
$result = $query->execute($parameters);
return ($result) ? $query->fetch() : 0;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using this sql, it returns 'Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous'. I've changed 'WHERE id=:id' for 'WHERE article.id=:id' and I get close to what I want. Here's a [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6i6w8p). What I'm wondering now is how to process this result with PHP to end up with a clean array to work with. I'm updating my question.

Comment: @sunburst I think that this solve your question, if you have another question you must close this as correct and open another question in the site